# Four particles are situated at the corners of a square of side ‘a’ and move at a constant speed v.

Tags: physics, kinematics

> Each particle maintains a direction towards the particle at the next corner. Time when particles will meet each other will be $\frac{2a}{\sqrt n v}$. Find the value of n

**MY SOLUTION**

The particles at adjacent corners will move with speed Vi and Vj. Therefore, relative velocity of first particle wrt second will be 
$$V_r=\sqrt{V^2+V^2}$$
$$=\sqrt 2 V$$
Distance to be covered is ‘a’

Time=$$\frac{a}{\sqrt 2 V}$$

Equating this with the original given expression
$$\frac{a}{\sqrt 2 v}=\frac{2a}{\sqrt n V}$$$$n=8$$
Answer given is 4, what have I don’t wrong?

Comment: The relative velocity of one wrt the other will not in thee direction of the line joining them. You need to take the velocity along the line joining them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Case of the 'mice problem' for $n=3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2804337/case-of-the-mice-problem-for-n-3)

Answer (score 1):

Consider what has happened after a small interval of time, $\delta t$. The first particle will have travelled a distance of $v \delta t$ **towards** the second particle whereas the second particle has travelled
a distance of $v \delta t$ **perpendicular** to the line joining them.

The distance between them is the hypotenuse of a right-angled triangle with the other sides having lengths $a-v \delta t$ and $v \delta t$. Ignoring distances as small as $ (\delta t)^2$,  the distance between the two particles is just $a-v \delta t$.

Therefore the distance between two particles will have decreased by $v \delta t$. This will be the same throughout the motion and so the particles will meet when $a=vt$, i.e. after time $\frac {a}{v}$.

In your solution, the relative velocity should just be $v$ along the line joining the particles since the second particle is moving at right angles to the first at every instant.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I am unable to understand

Comment: Sorry for delay,I've been travelling. Will add further explanation into the answer.