# 3 particles A,B and C are situated at the vertices of an equilateral triangle ABC of side d at t=0 .

Tags: geometry, systems-of-equations

My question is related to the [Mice problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mice_problem), with a slight modification.

**Question:** Three particles, $A$, $B$ and $C$, are situated at the vertices of an equilateral triangle $ABC$ of side length $d$.  Starting at $t=0$, each particle moves with a constant speed $v$.  $A$ always has its velocity along $AB$, $B$ along $BC$ and $C$ along $CA$. At what time will the particles meet?

*Modification*: What would be the equation of the curve followed by the bodies? (If it can be found; provide minimal amount of variables to find it if currently available ones don't suffice.)

*Additional challenge*: Could this entire problem (with the added modification) be generalized for an $n$-sided polygon following a particular path in each case?

*My understanding of this*:
So in the link above, you can see that it is described as a logarithmic spiral but how do we prove this? Moreover it references a pursuit curve, how do we know this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Case of the 'mice problem' for $n=3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2804337/case-of-the-mice-problem-for-n-3) The question is only about the distance covered, but the answer states the equation of the curve.

Comment: @joriki I agree that this question and the linked question are very similar.  However, this one is, I think, more general, and is not quite a duplicate.  In particular, I feel that a good answer to this question would supersede any answer to the linked question.  I've voted to leave this question open, in the hopes that it can attract a more general answer.

Comment: @XanderHenderson: Do you mean you didn't vote to close? Or have I missed some innovation in the voting system? :-)

Comment: @joriki I came across the question in the review queue, where the options are "close", "leave open", "edit", and "skip".  I voted "leave open" (well, actually, I voted "edit" and made some edits, but I wrote my comment before deciding to edit).

Comment: My question is related to a pursuit curve but it asks for a generalisation to an n-sided polygon.