# Path of particles moving from the corners of an equilateral triangle toward each other at a constant rate

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, mathematical-physics, kinematics

So I just was solving this standard problem when a question struck my mind. What is the nature of this path? I tried my best and all i was able to do was to prove that it is not a circle. Here is the pic:

[image]

Basically three particles starts moving with a constant speed from their respective corner of an equilateral triangle such that velocity is one particle is always directed to another.
Once again, I am trying to find the nature of the path followed by any particle.

Comment: See nice images for these curves called "pursuit curves" https://mathcurve.com/courbes2d.gb/poursuite/poursuitemutuelle.shtml I thought at first they are logarithmic spirals but the fact that the speed is constant make me a little doubt now..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Case of the 'mice problem' for $n=3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2804337/case-of-the-mice-problem-for-n-3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's choose a coordinate system with the origin $O$ at the centre of the triangle and with a particle initially at $(1,0)$.
At every moment the particles lie at the vertices of an equilateral triangle, their distances $r$ from $O$ being equal and their polar angles $\theta$ differing by $120°$.

Velocity vector $\vec v$ of the first particle is directed towards the second particle: its projection along the radial direction is $v_r=\dot r=-v\cos30°=-(\sqrt3/2)v$, while its projection along the azimuthal direction is $v_\theta=r\dot\theta=v\cos60°=(1/2)v$.
It follows that:
$$
{dr\over d\theta}={\dot r\over\dot\theta}=-\sqrt3r,
$$
which can be solved to yield
$$
r=e^{-\sqrt3\theta}.
$$
This is the polar equation of a logarithmic spiral.

[image]

Comment: [+1] Nice presentation